# Unable to change the color of web part titles

Tags: 2013, css

I'm able to change the font size and font weight of web part titles with

```
.ms-webpart-titleText {
    font-size: 27px;
    generic-family: Serif| font-family: Georgia;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

but it doesn't allow me to change the color of the font. Any ideas why this may be? I have tried (separately) all of the following:

```
.ms-webpart-titleText {
    color: red !important;
}

.ms-webpart-titleText {
    color: #FF0000 !important;
}

.ms-webpart-titleText {
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

Edit: I just found that the color is changed in some parts of the site but not others. For example, the color of the title text for Site Contents has changed to red, but not the title text of my two homepage web parts:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time the anchor tag or span inside the `ms-webpart-titleText` control
Try the following CSS

```
.ms-webpart-titleText > a,
.ms-webpart-titleText span
{
   color: #2b2b2b; //#2b2b2b !important;
}
```

Comment: This worked. I will mark it as the answer once it lets me.

Comment: Glad I have solved your problem.